# How to retrieve files from a Microsoft Surface Go 2 with broken screen?

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, hardware-failure, microsoft-surface, data-transfer

I dropped my Surface (running Windows 10) and [broke the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnxA6.jpg).

I have important files in it. How can I retrieve them?

Is it possible to connect it to an external display and then copy the files? I have another laptop, can I use it as a display? Or is it possible to connect it to my laptop via USB and retrieve the data? Taking the SSD out and read it with a reader seems too hard for me.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches I suggest for this.

1. To start without the native screen, you likely need a dock with an external monitor. This will work.

You can try just connecting an external monitor, but you may need to log in first on the broken screen.  Wait for the startup, enter your user name and password and see if the external screen takes over. I don't think it will and the screen you have may prevent switching. You can only try.

2. Take the machine to a local shop and have them remove the drive and recover files. You were uncertain about doing this yourself.

Comment: Thanks John. 
I don't have experience with external screens. Is this the dock you were talking about? 

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Adapter-Syntech-Thunderbolt-Compatible-MacBook-Gray/dp/B07M64KG2Q/ref=asc_df_B07M64KG2Q/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=294797661583&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=4576419555569694725&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1006598&hvtargid=pla-638086411883&psc=1

When connecting the Surface to external screen using the dock, do you need to do anything in the OS before the external screen can work?

Comment: I can't see on the Surface screen so no operations are possible.

Comment: With a dock, you can leave the screen closed and start the machine. It will start normally with the screen attached to the dock. This is a common arrangement in businesses.  With respect to the dock you have shown, you need to make sure it has a video connector. Look in the Microsoft Store for Surface docks.

Comment: Thanks, but will I need to, say, press a "Confirm connection to external screen" button on the Surface, before the external screen can work? I'm not able to press any on-screen button on Surface...

Comment: If the screen doesn't work and if you cannot see it, then you need a proper dock to be able to start directly from an external monitor attached to the dock.

Comment: Thanks John, will give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

Just disconnect your internal screen and boot with your external screen connected.
It worked with my Surface Go 1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).